# drupal content not visible on site (or backend)

Tags: drupal-7

All our content is gone, both on the frontend as the backend. Only the titels are there

If I check the database I still see the content in field_data_body. Rebuilding the nodes didn't work.

When I look this problem up, all are pointing to the organic group module. That I need to disable this. But I never installed this.

Anybody any idea to solve this (and what did I do the mess this up?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by deleting fields in your content type, or by disabling modules that provide the fields.

Also this can be caused by input filters being incorrect, check the enabled input formats, and lastly check user access control and make sure that all users can "access content".

Good luck!